# ElasticSearch Filter by sum of nested documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6, elasticsearch-7, nested-object

I am trying to filter products where a sum of properties in the nested *filtered* objects is in some range.

I have the following mapping:

```
{
  "product": {
    "properties": {
      "warehouses": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "stock_level": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example data:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "warehouses": [
    {
      "id": 2001,
      "stock_level": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 2002,
      "stock_level": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 2003,
      "stock_level": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

In ElasticSearch 5.6 I used to do this:

```
GET products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        [
          {
            "script": {
              "script": {
                "source": """
int total = 0;
for (def warehouse: params['_source']['warehouses']) {
  if (params.warehouse_ids == null || params.warehouse_ids.contains(warehouse.id)) {
    total += warehouse.stock_level;
  }
}
boolean gte = true;
boolean lte = true;
if (params.gte != null) {
  gte = (total >= params.gte);
}
if (params.lte != null) {
  lte = (total <= params.lte);
}
return (gte && lte);

""",
                "lang": "painless",
                "params": {
                  "gte": 4
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that `params['_source']['warehouses']` no longer works in ES 6.8, and I am unable to find a way to access nested documents in the script.

I have tried:

- `doc['warehouses']` - returns error (“No field found for [warehouses] in mapping with types []" )
- `ctx._source.warehouses` - “Variable [ctx] is not defined.”

I have also tried to use scripted_field but it seems that scripted fields are getting calculated on the very last stage and are not available during query.

I also have a sorting by the same logic (sort products by the sum of stocks in the given warehouses), and it works like a charm:

```
  "sort": {
    "warehouses.stock_level": {
      "order": "desc",
      "mode": "sum",
      "nested": {
        "path": "warehouses"
        "filter": {
           "terms": {
             "warehouses.id": [2001, 2003]
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But I can't find a way to access this sort value either :(

Any ideas how can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue. It turns out the change [occurred somewhere around 6.4](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-not-access-to-params-source-in-script-score/153851/3) during refactoring and while accessing `_source` is strongly discouraged, it looks like people are still using / wanting to use it.

Here's a workaround taking advantage of the [`include_in_root` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-params).

1. Adjust your mapping

```
PUT product
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "warehouses": {
        "type": "nested",
        "include_in_root": true,     <--
        "properties": {
          "stock_level": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. Drop & reindex
3. Reconstruct the individual warehouse items in a for loop while accessing the flattened values:

```
GET product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": """
                  int total = 0;
                  
                  def ids = doc['warehouses.id'];
                  def levels = doc['warehouses.stock_level'];
                  
                  for (def i = 0; i <  ids.length; i++) {
                    def warehouse = ['id':ids[i], 'stock_level':levels[i]];
                    
                    if (params.warehouse_ids == null || params.warehouse_ids.contains(warehouse.id)) {
                      total += warehouse.stock_level;
                    }
                  }
                  
                  boolean gte = true;
                  boolean lte = true;
                  if (params.gte != null) {
                    gte = (total >= params.gte);
                  }
                  if (params.lte != null) {
                    lte = (total <= params.lte);
                  }
                  return (gte && lte);
              """,
              "lang": "painless",
              "params": {
                  "gte": 4
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Be aware that this approach assumes that all warehouses include a non-null id and stock level.

Comment: Huge thanks Joe! The only thing I had to edit was casting warehouse.id to the same type (turned out array.contains(x) doesn't work if array items are ints, and x is long - again, worked fine in ES 5.6).

Comment: Nice, glad I could help!

Comment: It turned out to be incorrect. The problem is that `def ids = doc['warehouses.id'];` returns sorted IDs, so as `def levels = doc['warehouses.stock_level'];` - which means the connection between warehouse and level is lost...

Comment: If the field is set as `include_in_root`, the values will be flattened. That's the downside. If you need to iterate `params._source` (and thus keep the connections), you can do so through a `function_score` query as I illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66957242/8160318) (towards the end of the long answer.) That's the only option since ES `v6.4`.